# Child object is also getting saved

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am creating one to one relation ship using entity framework. I created two classes Student and IssueMaster. Both classes derived from base Entity class

```
public class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class IssueMaster : Entity
{
    public IssueMaster()
    {
        IssueDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping for Student and IssueMaster classes is,

```
public class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        ToTable("Student");

        Property(x => x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        Property(x => x.MobileNo)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(10)
            .IsFixedLength();

       Property(x=>x.Address).HasMaxlength(50);
    }
}

public class IssueMasterMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IssueMaster>
{
    public IssueMasterMap()
    {
        ToTable("IssueMaster");

        Property(x => x.IssueDate).IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ReturnDate).IsOptional();
        HasRequired(x => x.Student);
    }
}
```

The save method for saving entity is

```
    public static bool Save<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        var context = SessionManager.GetCurrentContext;
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
```

the problem is when we save IssueMaster object in database, the Student object attached to that IssueMaster object also getting saved in database.

What to do in code so that, when we save IssueMaster object and Student object from database   attached to that IssueMaster object, only save IssueMaster object? 
(like SaveOrUpdate method does in Nhibernate)

Comment: Do you want to save brand new IssueMaster object which doesn't exist in database, but you want that it have `null` in student_id column?

Comment: yes i want to save new IssueMaster object with existing student id value in Student_id column,Student record already exist in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is setting entry state to *Added* - that changes whole object graph to *Added* state (i.e. including all referenced entities). You can avoid adding new `Student` entry if you will use `StudentId` property instead of using `Student` object in saved entity. Or if you will manually set entity state of student to *Unchanged* or *Modified*.

First option is making your `Save` method non-generic. That will allow you to set navigation property state directly:

```
 context.Entry(issueMaster.Student).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

But if you want to have generic method, your only option is reflection (which is performance hit). Thus all your entities are inherited from base `Entity` type, you can get properties which are inherited from `Entity` type and check their id. If it has `Guid.Empty` value, then object is new and was not saved in database, otherwise you should set appropriate state of entity:

```
public static bool SaveOnlyAddedEntities<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
{
    var context = new ZorgContext();
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    var entry = context.Entry(entity);

    Type type = typeof(T);
    var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;

    var unchangedDependencies =
        type.GetProperties(flags)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity)))
            .Select(p => (Entity)p.GetValue(entity))
            .Where(e => e.Id != Guid.Empty);

    foreach (var dependency in unchangedDependencies)
        context.Entry(dependency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Note: this approach shows working with non-collection properties.

Comment: It works, thanks, can u share any link that describes relationships with entity framework code first deeply?

Comment: @Mahendra I recommend you to watch Julie Lerman EF series from pluralsight (especially [Entity Framework in the Enterprise](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/efarchitecture)) you can also search for her articles, I believe they will also contain explanation of EntityState changes